# Opensea shows airdrop when randomnize token id

Tags: erc-721, chainlink

I'm minting the nft with random token but Opensea showing "airdrop" in transaction history. I want to keep this minted. help me please.

```
function mint() public payable {
    require(
        LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee,
        "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet"
    );
    requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
    requestToSender[requestId] = msg.sender;
}
function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
  _safeMint(requestToSender[requestId], randomness);
}
```

[image]

https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/0x935cb64b44e915c52890e3e829635cc9c9038ccb/48

Answer (score 0):

I believe what's happening here is that OpenSea is showing this as an airdrop due to the mint function being called by an address that is NOT the receiver address.

When the `msg.sender` calls `mint()` it initiates a call to `requestRandomness()` this invokes the VRF Coordinator to generate a random value and call `fulfillRandomness()`. In the `fulfillRandomness()` function the `_safeMint()` function actually mints the token. The fact that the VRF Coordinator is the one *"minting"* the NFT is why it appears as an *"airdrop"*.